# Issues downloading Angular cli on MacOS, ENOTEMPTY errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Relatively new to MacOS and coding on the whole and I'm having some issues downloading Angular and getting it to work. I'm following a Udemy course and have installed NodeJS:

```
% node -v
v18.16.1
```

but when I use

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! dest /Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-o7RtjkzL
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' -> '/Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/.cli-o7RtjkzL'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ioanevans/.npm/_logs/2023-07-13T17_19_43_833Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried a lot of pages on here with no success so if someone believes there's a good solution to redirect me to possibly, that would be great.
EDIT: I have tried clearing the cache and redownloading, for example:

```
(base) ioanevans@Ioans-MacBook-Air ~ % npm cache verify

Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.003s
(base) ioanevans@Ioans-MacBook-Air ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli

added 239 packages in 2m

36 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
(base) ioanevans@Ioans-MacBook-Air ~ % ng new pw
zsh: command not found: ng
```

Comment: did you `sudo` install that earlier? what are the permissions on `/Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli`?

Comment: I believe that I would of used sudo @Daniel A. White.   % ls -l /Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli

total 24
-rwxr-xr-x    1 ioanevans  staff  1073 13 Jul 18:56 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x    1 ioanevans  staff   314 13 Jul 18:56 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    5 ioanevans  staff   160 13 Jul 18:56 bin
drwxr-xr-x    6 ioanevans  staff   192 13 Jul 18:56 lib
drwxr-xr-x  205 ioanevans  staff  6560 13 Jul 18:56 node_modules
-rwxr-xr-x    1 ioanevans  staff  1641 13 Jul 18:56 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    9 ioanevans  staff   288 13 Jul 18:56 src `

Comment: @DanielA.White could it be something to do with when I use `echo $PATH` it returns `/Users/ioanevans/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/ioanevans/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
`.  see that the /Users/ioanevans/.npm-global/bin directory is not included in the PATH variable and wondering whether this maybe of issue?

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White, I’ve got it now